# nstableview how to fit text

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview, row-height

The problem is to fit text into cell. With cell.textfield.sizetofit() and layouts I can create text on more than 1 line, but visible is only one

[image: text cut]
if I make text size small I can see second line but cut by half

Comment: You need to either increase the row height (`tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`) based on the row number, or if you want dynamically sized cells, ensure you have configured layout constraints correctly on the `UITableViewCell` and use UITableViewAutomaticDimension (and also set an `estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:`).

Comment: it's an osx application

Comment: Your problem isn't really how to fit text into cell.  The real problems are that you don't explain what the cell is and even that you don't say whether you are using cell-based or view-based NSTableView.

Comment: it's view-based. So if just take the new osx application project, create table (view-based) and load text into cell i.e. from array - how to make visible whole text? p.s. constraints will make borders (as i understand), .sizetofit() will make text on more than 1 line, preferred width = first runtime layout width will make width auto adjustable and seems something else is missing